# R not plotting in order (group)

Tags: r, plot

I'm fairly new to R, 
here is the code below:

```
volume <- c(388,499,477,408,480,559,347,995,303,506,402,285,360,327,222,452,385,369,541,257,349,503,227,410,254,229,328,377,292,546,195,336,367)
stage <- c(rep("baseline",11),rep("preRT",11),rep("postRT",11))
prostatic_volume <- data.frame(volume,stage)

plot(volume ~ stage, 
     data=prostatic_volume,
     main="Change in prostatic volume during treatment",
     ylab="Prostatic volume, #voxels")
```

I want it to plot in the order of `baseline`, `preRt`, `postRt`. But for some reason it mixes up the order of `preRT` and `postRT`.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Data frame can be corrected before plotting:

```
prostatic_volume$stage = factor(stage, levels=c('baseline','preRT','postRT'))
```